# Stripe Subscription with multi coupons - How to buy a product, so as not to pay for existing products again at a new coupon discount?

Tags: stripe-payments

How to buy a product with a new coupon, buy a product with a new coupon forever, so as not to pay for existing products again at a new coupon discount? That is, I want to use a one-time coupon for the first time, and with renewed subscriptions to buy the product for the coupon forever.

One billing period:

1)20 dollars * 10 quantity * (1 - 0,62) coupon-discount one-time = 76 dollars paid = 10 quantity

2)+ 20 dollars * 1 quantity * (1 - 0,10) coupon-discount forever = 18 dollars paid = 11 quantity

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking unfortunately. Typically Stripe coupons apply to the entire gross Invoice amount, you can't really apply a coupon to a single quantity of a product when you're updating the subscription.

Comment: It would also help to rephrase your question. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve. But if you want to retain the discounted price for subsequent invoices, then the best approach is to create a customized Price for the particular user's subscription.